# Update Outline Header Cell if child rows have 1 or more populated values

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Im really struggling here in scanning outline and child rows. In my code below (see attached Images) I have a worksheet (Figure A) in which I want to scan column C and when the value is 1 (Outline) I then want to scan all nested rows until I hit the next outline which will be 1 and you can in Column C the level number is assigned to nested groups so when the level number in column C is 1 then the same routine needs to loop again until the last row in Column C (or last outline). Once an outline (level 1) is found I then wants to scan all nested rows / subgroups to see if there is a value in Column D (Load Number). If at least 1 row has a value then I want to update the cell value on the original parent Level with the status "SPLIT LOAD" else "SINGLE LOAD" (See Figure D). Here is my code and im just going round in circles as it is not scanning my child rows.

```
Sub ScanRows()
     Dim LoadNumber As Integer
     Dim LevelNumber As Integer
     Dim LoadStatus As String
     Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

     LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
       
     For i = 1 To LastRow
         
       If Range("C" & i).Value = 1 And Range("D" & i).Value <> "N/A" Then
        
            LoadNumber = Range("D" & i).Value
            LoadStatus = Range("E" & i).Value
            
           If Range("C" & i).Value > 1 And IsEmpty(Range("D" & i).Value) Then
               ' Update the Loadstatus "SINGLE LOAD"
               Else
               ' Update the Loadstatus "SINGLE LOAD"
           End If
            
     End If
    
 Next i
 
 End Sub
```

Thankyou

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be easy to do with one helper column. Add a new column d with the formula
=IF(C2=1,D1+1,D1)

and then your previous d would be the formula
=IF(C2=1,IF(AND(C2=1,COUNTIFS(D:D,D2,E:E,">="&0)>1),"SPLIT LOAD","SINGLE LOAD"),"")

Comment: Thankyou so much for your response and works exactly as I want it. Your help is so appreciated. Once again thankyou

Comment: Glad that helped! As I was thinking about this more, if you really wanted a macro solution, you could create a macro that adds a row, autofills those formulas, pastes as values and then deletes the helper column. Let me know if you need help doing that.

Comment: Much prefer this solution but thankyou and respect for your support buddy! Im new to vba and coding and have really enjoyed learning but time was on my side for a solution hence the post. Didnt want to come across lazy :-) The solution you have sorted for me is a BOM (Bill of materials) extract from our PLM system in which we want to post process with the relevant logic to provide a transport packing list so our production team can load the relevant production parts in the relevant containers. This is why the load is important! I will just stick to PLM Systems I think lol.........thankyou

Comment: Marci guess what the customer is now asking for it to be a macro. The reason being is the number of level 1 (parents) and child rows could be different based on the extract they get from the BOM itself. I have created a macro to easily create the Helper column and populate the formula but my issue now is how to make both columns work based on the number of level 1's and total number of rows as they could be different everytime buddy

Comment: Could you post another screenshot of how the data could look?

Comment: Hi marci I cant do that right now as I would need to get another BOM extract but basically it will either be more Level 1's with nested levels or fewer Level 1's. The structure will be the same as in parent / nested levels buddy